# Android application close after click button

Tags: php, android

I have application to add new id to database using php. If I click button <kbd>create id</kbd> in my program it always closes everything but the data inserted in database.

I don't know how to fix it. In my `logcat` there is no information about any error.

This is my code:

```
Toolbar toolbar;
// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
EditText inputusername;
EditText inputpassword;
EditText inputnamegm;
TextView registerErrorMsg;
Button createidgm;
// url to create news
private static String url_create_idgm = "http://192.168.1.111/add/create_idgm.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_ERROR = "error";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_idgm);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    TypedValue typedValueColorPrimaryDark = new TypedValue();
    CreateIDGM.this.getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.colorPrimary, typedValueColorPrimaryDark, true);
    final int colorPrimaryDark = typedValueColorPrimaryDark.data;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(colorPrimaryDark);
    }

    // Edit Text
    inputusername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputusername);
    inputpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputpassword);
    inputnamegm = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputname);
    registerErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.error);
    // Create button
    createidgm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreate);

    // button click event
    createidgm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // creating new product in background thread
            new NetCheck().execute();
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Create new product
 * */
class NetCheck extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(CreateIDGM.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Creating ID Game Master..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Creating product
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        String name = inputusername.getText().toString();
        String version = inputpassword.getText().toString();
        String description = inputnamegm.getText().toString();

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", version));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", description));

        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_idgm,
                "POST", params);

        // check log cat fro response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        // check for success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully created product
                //Toast.makeText(CreateIDGM.this, "Success Create ID Game Master ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ListTopGM.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // closing this screen
                finish();
            } else {
                // failed to create product
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Can someone help me solve this?

Answer (score 0):

**doInBackground** is not a part of ui thread. So you can't do anything about ui, for your example starting a new screen is a ui job but you're calling it in a backthread and this causes crash. So just move your startActivity block to onPostExecute. Also, finish() closes your entire screen. One last thing, your catch block just catches JSONExceptions and this is not enough in your case. If you change it to just Exception then you'll see the exception log in logcat.